# Avoid forced callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose database query

```
var player;
Users.findById(req.user._id,function(err,user){     
    console.log('>>> user: '+user); //----2
    player = user;
    });
console.log('>>> player: '+player);    // ----1
```

in this code `1` executes before `2` because of `2` being inside a callback.

Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: assuming findById is async then no

Comment: Yes, put it in the same callback, or in another callback. Promises help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create another function (lets say `log`) in the same namespace as `player` variable, put `console.log('>>> player: '+player);` to it and call `log` after you assigning `player`.

Thus, `player` variable is visible for **both** `findById` callback and `log` function.

Here is the code:

```
var player;
Users.findById(req.user._id,function(err,user){     
    console.log('>>> user: '+user);
    player = user;
    log();
});
function log() {
    console.log('>>> player: '+player);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to call 1 from withing the callback. For example, something like that:

```
var player;
Users.findById(req.user._id,function(err,user){
    console.log('>>> user: '+user);    // ----1
    player = user;
    showPlayer();
});
var showPlayer = function() {
    console.log('>>> player: '+player);    // ----2
}
```

Comment: this will not work because you call `showPlayer()` before `player = user`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var player;
Users.findById(req.user._id,function(err,user){     
    console.log('>>> user: '+user); //----1
    player = user;
    console.log('>>> player: '+player);    // ----2
});
```

UPDATE:

this might be an alternative

```
var mainFunction = function(player){
  if(!player){
    Users.findById(req.user._id,function(err,user){     
      console.log('>>> user:', user);      
      mainFunction(user);
    });
  } else {
    console.log('>>> player: '+player);
  }
};
mainFunction();
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I failed to explain, but the whole point is that I don't want to put my other entire code inside the `Users.findById(...function(){`

Comment: them create a separate function and make a call inside the callback